# ES6 Partial Object Destructuring Default Parameters In A Separated Object

Tags: javascript, destructuring, default-parameters

Okay so there's a lot of similar questions here but none that actually address this.
What if I want to save the default parameters of a function on a separated object, in a separated file and then I want the function to use this default parameters only if not specified when calling it?

Example:

```
export const defaultParameters = { a: "foo", b: "bar"}
```

And then in another file:

```
import {defaultParameters} from ./utils.js

myFunction = function(defaultParameters = {}){
   const {a, b} = defaultParameters;
   console.log(a,b);
}
```

What I want for it to do is that calling

```
myFunction({a: "hello"})
```

should print

```
"hello", "bar"
```

But that's not how that works and I'm trying to figure this out. Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you use `const { a,b } = { ...defaultParameters, ...options }`. Since options comes last in that it will override any other parameters. You just made a merged object that you can query.

Comment: By naming your function's parameter `defaultParameters`, you're overwriting the imported one.

Comment: You probably can't find anything because what you ask for is impossible. Moreover, [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Seems like the real thing you're after is have  "default fallback values for a parameter object" which is both possible and would give you relevant results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do it directly in the parameter, but you can inside the function..

eg..

```
import {defaultParameters} from ./utils.js

myFunction = function(params = {}){
   const {a, b} = {...defaultParameters, ...params};
   console.log(a,b);
}
```

Comment: Well, its actually ugly. Some value depends on some outer value. Usually you try to make a function as pure as possible

Comment: Thanks @Keith! I got it to work. 
@bill.gates why do you think its ugly? What do you mean by a "pure" function? Do you have any alternative way you would approach this problem?

Comment: @DanielGuedes pure means the function return values are identical for identical arguments. This function has side-effects. If `defaultParameters` are changed or missing you receive different results by the same input. Sometimes you cannot achieve to make a function pure, but you should try getting towards purity. alternatives would be to pass `defaultParameters` as an second argument like `(params = {}, defaultParameters = {})` and then you pass it when you call it.

Comment: @bill.gates  defaultParameters,  is obviously a global constant, as such this function is indeed pure, there would be no side effects.

Comment: @Keith just change something in `defaultParameters` and you receive different output by the same input `params`

Comment: @bill.gates  I repeat, defaultParameters is obviously meant to be a global constant..  You would do similar things in other languages, like C , C++, GO, Rust, you name it.   Not putting global constants in another file would be WET, and not DRY, and that's worse than not been a pure function.

Comment: Oh I see, but in my application that's actually my goal. If something is not specified I want the function to grab it from defautParemeters, and as @Keith mentioned it is going to be a global constant and I'm not going to change it dynamically, but I still want the option to manually change it from time to time as my code unravel. Thank you! Never got as quick and efficient reponse as for this question!